# Get disk space using wmi class only the size nothing else

Tags: wmi

i use a simple call using the WMI

> (get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk).Size
>   (get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk).Freespace

I only want the info about the size in MB or in GB...i do not want a table or something like that...solutions for that are already avaliable
How can this be accomplished in a one-line…?

> PS C:\Users\XXXXXXXX> (get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk).size
>   2550860308484992762052608

Would love to see here 250 GB or so... again only one by one no table….

Answer (score 0):

Divide by 1024 / 1024 /1024
There are 1024 Bytes in a Kilobyte, 1024 Kilobytes in a Megabyte, etc...So keep dividing by 1024 until you don't have comma's

**Edit**
I'm not sure what that number is but the amount of Bytes in 250GB is
268435456000

Comment: Sorry found my Problem .. as 2 liner i got back the Size of my localdisk and the Network attached Drive ... silly Mistake... Thats the Reason it did Not Match up ... thanks for your help